# How to improve the quality of a UIPickerController image resolution? Xcode obj-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, resolution

Is it possible to improve the quality of a UIPickerController image resolution? Xcode 7.1, Obj-C.
What I have done is i've made the UIpickerController image smaller that what is previously was, causing it to be blurred. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try UIImagePickerController, it's property 'UIImagePickerControllerQualityType' is about video quality. Hope this will help you